# Select Statement Query to exclude rows with duplicate values

Tags: mysql

I need a SQL query using `select` statement that excludes duplicate rows that has the same `Start_Time`, `End_Time`, and `ReasonCode`

```
EventID       Start_Time         End_Time             ReasonCode 

 122         1/3/2015 0:27      1/3/2015 1:32      No Trouble Found
 123         1/3/2015 0:27      1/3/2015 1:32      No Trouble Found
 124         1/3/2015 0:27      1/3/2015 1:32      No Trouble Found
 125         1/31/2015 14:35    1/31/2015 14:56    LinkupDown
```

The resulting output would look like:

```
EventID       Start_Time         End_Time             ReasonCode 

 122         1/3/2015 0:27      1/3/2015 1:32      No Trouble Found
 125         1/31/2015 14:35    1/31/2015 14:56    LinkupDown
```

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Google for GROUP BY:
https://www.google.ca/search?q=mysql%20group%20by%20example

Comment: distinct or group by are what you are looking for. distinct if you don't really care about EventID, and group by if you want a min(EventId)

Comment: Ah, you know guys I didn't even think about the group statement. I was figuring I would need to use a fancy `Case` statement to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove duplicate rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)

Comment: The above doesn't work, I cannot make changes to the database tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the group by and the min function to the query will create the desired result set.  [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22774/11/0).

```
select min(eventid) EventID, DATE_FORMAT(Start_Time,'%m/%d/%Y %H:%i') Start_Time, DATE_FORMAT(End_Time,'%m/%d/%Y %H:%i') End_Time, ReasonCode
from mytable
group by ReasonCode
order by eventid
```